# How to set product OUT OF STOCK and enable Manage Stock for this product in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock, stock-status, stock-availability

I work on Magento 2.4 and I'd like to enable programmatically for selected products "Manage Stock" option and set status Out Of stock. Like here:
[image: Product Manage Stock settings]

But I did not found how it should be done in Magento higher than 2.4 I found that \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface is deprecated. Product model setStocData() also is deprecated.

**How it should be done without use of any deprecated classes?**

Answer (score 0):

yes i too checked and the classes are deprecated perhaps you can try this - from your question i get to know that you want to set the "Manage Stock" and "Stock Status" for a product.

Please follow the below code where i hit the rest API endpoint and the product's stock settings gets changes.You can also follow this in your PHP file or JS file by hitting this API.

endpoint = http://local.magento243.com/rest/V1/products/24-MB01

HTTP Method = PUT

Body request params =

{
"product": {
"extension_attributes": {
"stock_item": {
"is_in_stock": false,
"manage_stock": false
}
}
}
}

Authorisation is also needed as Bearer token.